# How to import an instantiated object from a module

Tags: python, oop

Trying import a module and an object it instantiates, but keeps saying the object doesn't exist.

**car.py**

```
class Car:

    def __init__(self, year, make, model):
        self.year = year
        self.make = make
        self.model = model

    def __str__(self):
        return "Make: {} Model: {} Year: {}".format(self.make, self.model, self.year)

stratus = Car(1995, "Dodge", "Stratus")
```

**main.py**

```
import car

print(stratus.__str__())
```

Should print the car's attributes, but comes back with error:
*NameError: name 'stratus' is not defined*

Comment: Don't call `__str__` explicitly; use `str(stratus)`.

Comment: @chepner he doesn’t even need to do that. Calling __str__ or str(), the print statement already does that. Just saying for clean code.

Comment: @Drizzle I wasn't referring to this context; I was referring to *any* explicit call to `__str__`. (Exception: `super().__str__()` when overriding an inherited `__str__` method.) Whether a call to `str` is necessary is another matter, as you point out.

Answer (score 5):

Either:

```
import car
print(car.stratus)
```

or

```
from car import stratus
print(stratus)
```

Comment: Note that `print()` will call `str()` for an object, and `str()` will use the object's `__str__()` method, so no need to call any of those things yourself.